# Showing button based of specific log in id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, strongloop

For now, i am able to hide the button if the user is not logged in and it'll show when the user is logged in using the ng-show tag in html page. But what i want is the button to show only when the user logs in with a specific log in id. for example: ng-show="currentUser" where email == example01@gmail.com or currentUser==example01@gmail.com. Im not really sure how this works but how do I do something like that?

### log in function

```
    function login(email, password) {
  return User
    .login({email: email, password: password})
    .$promise
    .then(function(response) {
      $rootScope.currentUser = {
        id: response.user.id,
        tokenId: response.id,
        email: email
      };
    });
}
```

## html

```
<button type="button" ng-show="currentUser" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Send sms for selected </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way  `ng-show="(currentUser.id == '1234')"`:

```
    <button type="button" ng-show="(currentUser.id == '1234')" 
                class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" 
                data-target="#myModal">Send sms for selected 
    </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work: `currentUser==example01@gmail.com` but not the best way to put email in DOM. you could also use a function that checks if a specific user is logged in for example:

```
ng-show="checkCurrentUser()"
```

and

```
$rootScope.checkCurrentUser = function () {
    $rootscope.currentUser == example01@gmail.com ? return true : return false;
}
```